# How to split an array into two with considering values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

Sorry I have searched many thread related to this question but I couldn't find something useful for my case.

I have an array like this :

```
[
  "service_name" => [
    0 => "1212"
    1 => "zzz"
  ]
  "service_price" => [
    0 => "12"
    1 => "11"
  ]
  "time" => [
    0 => "121"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "service_in_country" => [
    0 => "usa"
    1 => "usa"
  ]
  "service_in_city" => [
    0 => "la"
    1 => "lv"
  ]
]
```

I want this:

```
   [
     "service_name" =>1212,
     "service_price"=>12,
     "time" => 121,
     "service_in_country"=>usa,
     "service_in_city"=>la
   ],
   [
     "service_name" =>zzz,
     "service_price"=>11,
     "time" => 1,
     "service_in_country"=>usa,
     "service_in_city"=>lv
   ]
```

Actually all first `key=>value` become a new array and all second `key=>value` become the new second array

P.S:

I'm using Laravel if you know any helper or collection.

Comment: have you tried `array_merge`?

Comment: an usual foreach successfully do this

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function

```
function diverse_request_array($vector = array()) 
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($vector as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
        {
            $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["service_name"]=>
    string(4) "1212"
    ["service_price"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["time"]=>
    string(3) "121"
    ["service_in_country"]=>
    string(3) "usa"
    ["service_in_city"]=>
    string(2) "la"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["service_name"]=>
    string(3) "zzz"
    ["service_price"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["time"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["service_in_country"]=>
    string(3) "usa"
    ["service_in_city"]=>
    string(2) "lv"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the array like this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/789247)**

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    foreach($v as $ind => $val)
    {
        $result[$ind][$k] = $val;
    }
}
```